# How to save/load objects in a game

Tags: c#, xna, load, save

I was wondering what is the best way to save and load a game in progess in XNA on a PC game? I given some thought and wrote some code but I feel my methods are weak and I can do it in a better way. My method was to have a ToString() method for each game object. Then I would write that to a file and convert it to bytes(to discourage tampering) and saved the file. Then when load time came it convert the bytes back to strings and I would read each one a re instantiate those objects in a new game. So any suggestions? Or is my method a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into serialization? It converts the object directly to bytes and then converts the file directly into an object again.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) is a MSoft link on how to do it.

It's faster and cheaper (for CPU) then converting to a string then parsing. There may still be better ways though. Those would require quite a bit more work then Serialization, which is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://easystorage.codeplex.com/ it handles most of the headache when it comes to this kind of stuff.

Also if you ever plan on porting this to Windows Phone or Xbox, it is supported.